# quarkus unable to name a datasource "query"

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

regarding Quarkus version 3.6.6,

Checking out the quickstart from here https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts.git

On hibernate-orm-panache-quickstart:
Edit the application.properties with this content:

```
quarkus.datasource.query.db-kind=postgresql

quarkus.hibernate-orm.query.datasource=query
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query.packages=org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.entity,org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.repository
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query.sql-load-script=import.sql
```

Run the test: FAILED

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor#configurationDescriptorBuilding threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Model classes are defined for the default persistence unit, but no default datasource was found. The default EntityManagerFactory will not be created. To solve this, configure the default datasource. Refer to https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource for guidance.
```

Edit the application.properties with this content:

```
quarkus.datasource.query-service.db-kind=postgresql

quarkus.hibernate-orm.query-service.datasource=query-service
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query-service.packages=org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.entity,org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.repository
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query-service.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query-service.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.query-service.sql-load-script=import.sql
```

Run the test: PASS

Does the "query" is a reserved word ? Maybe the error should be more explicative on it - or maybe it should bé possible to name a datasource query.

Regards,
Damien

Comment: Yes, `query` is a reserved configuration section to configure e.g null ordering or query plan cache size. Here is the related [configuration reference](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#quarkus-hibernate-orm_quarkus.hibernate-orm.query-query-related-configuration)

Comment: Many thanks. I did not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

As @zforgo mentioned, this is probably Quarkus config getting confused by the fact that other configuration properties exist that start with `quarkus.hibernate-orm.query`. I opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/38321 to address this, though I'm not sure it's possible to fix it.

Maybe you can try using quotes around `query` to resolve the ambiguity (that's generally a good practice for names in configuration property keys):

```
quarkus.datasource."query".db-kind=postgresql

quarkus.hibernate-orm."query".datasource=query
quarkus.hibernate-orm."query".packages=org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.entity,org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache.repository
quarkus.hibernate-orm."query".database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm."query".log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm."query".sql-load-script=import.sql
```

I haven't tried though, so I'm not sure it will work.